# Data is not inserted in database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-express

```
String nam = name.Text;
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tab(tname)VALUES(@val)", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", nam);
cn.Open();
int cnt = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Message:" + cnt);
cn.Close();
```

This is my code. The message shows `Message:1`. But the value is not inserted in database test. Table name is tab with column name `tname`.

What will possibly be wrong?

Comment: you are missing `;` at last of the connection string. I am not sure.

Comment: return 1 means the code actually inserts into database, maybe you seems to need to refresh management studio to see actual result

Answer (score 0):

This whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file (to the output directory where Visual Studio is running your app from) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `cn.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `TestDB`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TestDB;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...